# Контент в приложении и авторские права

Tags: контент, авторские-права

Частая ситуация: Пишется приложение, возникает необходимость в контенте(иконки,звуки и тд).
Что первое приходит в голову это скачать с сети уже имеющиеся, ок. Скачиваем, используем, но возникает мысль, а чьи они? Закреплено ли авторство за иконками,звуками и т.д. ?
Не придется ли отвечать за использование этого всего?

Если да, то достаточно ли мне, на 1% сменить тон иконки, чтобы она стала уникальной?) Возможно, вопрос не сюда нужно было задавать, но если кто-то разбирается, то буду рад выслушать.

Comment: Вопрос из рода "ни о чем, мне нужна карма" :)

Comment: Если вы продаёте программу за деньги, не ищите возможностей для обхода закона. Лучше нарисуйте свои иконки или купите их (с возможностью редистрибуции), и смело используйте.

Если же вы пишете программу за зарплату, пусть контент покупает работодатель, обходить закон -- не ваше дело, ваша зарплата наверное не покрывает возможную отсидку.

Comment: Francesco, разве такие вопросы задают ради кармы? На мой взгляд, вопрос весьма специфичен.

VladD - спасибо, начинаю осваивать рисование)

Comment: А насчёт смены тона на 1% -- попробуйте сменить тон на 1% в логотипе Apple и использовать в качестве эмблемы своей программы, посмотрите, через какое время начнутся проблемы. Суды во многих странах руководствуются здравым смыслом: если очевидно, что это перекрашенное эппловское яблоко, разница даже в 2% не спасёт вас.

Comment: Я имел ввиду иконки типа 23x23(очень маленькие и все похожие на друг друга) и т.д. Кстати, карточные масти никому не принадлежат?

Comment: @alex91: думаю, нет, они существуют уже очень давно. Однако я не юрист, могу ошибаться.

---
С другой стороны, вспомните историю [South Butt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_South_Butt).

Comment: @VladD у South Butt кстати Happy End вот здесь на русском http://udivitelnoe.info/2012/04/04/the-north-face-против-the-south-butt/

Comment: @ReinRaus: Да, я это и имел в виду. В смысле, может и повезти :-)